r lrm from rms package and imputed data from mice
I apologize for my ignorance, I’m jumping into an analysis midway and would appreciate guidance on the appropriate functions to use for estimating odds ratios (ORs).
Here’s the situation: I’ve been provided with a dataset that has already been imputed using the mice package. The original dataset with missing values is not available, and the imputed dataset appears to have been generated using mice::complete(imputed_df, "long", include = FALSE). This is my starting point.
Here's the code to reproduce this dataset
library(mice)
library(rms)
library(parameters)
library(splines)

set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
# Number of observations
n <- 100

# outcome
y <- rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = 0.07)

# bmi
bmi <- runif(n, min = 16, max = 60)
bmi[sample(1:n, size = round(0.12 * n))] <- NA # Introduce missing values

# tiktok_ban
tiktok_ban <- sample(1:90, size = n, replace = TRUE)
#tiktok_ban[sample(1:n, size = round(0.05 * n))] <- 0 # Force some values to be 0

# sex
child_sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.49, 0.51))
child_sex[sample(1:n, size = round(0.05 * n))] <- NA # Introduce missing values

# Combine into a data frame
df <- data.frame(y, bmi, tiktok_ban, child_sex)

# View first rows of the dataset
head(df)

#

imputed_df <- mice(df, print = FALSE, m = 20, seed = 24415, method = "pmm", printFlag = FALSE)

imputed_df_l <- mice::complete(imputed_df, "long", include = FALSE)



The goal is to estimate the Odds Ratio of an event (y).
I am modelling tiktok_ban as nonlinear spline with jump at day 20
d    <- imputed_df_l
dd   <- datadist(d);  options(datadist='dd')


Hmisc::describe(imputed_df_l$tiktok_ban)

k  <- attr(rcs(imputed_df_l$tiktok_ban, 6), 'parms')
k

h <- function(x) {
  z <- cbind(rcspline.eval(x, k),
             jump=x >= 20)
  attr(z, 'nonlinear') <- 2 : ncol(z)
  z
}

I am able to estimate the OR for this model on individual imputed dataset
f <- lrm(y ~ child_sex + bmi +
             gTrans(tiktok_ban, h),
             data= subset(imputed_df_l, .imp == 1)) 

summary(f)


How do I scale this code to run on multiple imputed datasets and generate pooled Odds Ratios and create a plot of Odds Ratios versus tiktok_ban based on the final pooled results?
Please note I cannot change the imputed datasets imputed_df_l  , this is what I was given. Thanks in advance for any help
I have tried fit.mult.impute but ran into errors and unable to make it work for my usecase.

I've done something similar there. It follows Rubin's logic1, 2.
> PF <- by(imputed_df_l, ~ .imp, \(x) {
+   summary(lrm(y ~ child_sex + bmi + gTrans(tiktok_ban, h), data=x))
+ }) |> 
+   simplify2array()
> 
> m. <- length(unique(imputed_df_l$.imp))
> Q <- rowMeans(PF[, 'Effect', ])  ## calculate mean estimates
> U <- rowMeans(PF[, 'S.E.', ])  ## calculate within variances
> B <- rowSums(((PF[, 'Effect', ] - Q)^2))/(m. - 1)  ## calculate between variances 
> T <- U + (1 + 1/m.)*B  ## calculate total variances 
> cbind(Estimate=Q, 'Std. Error'=sqrt(T))
                             Estimate Std. Error
bmi                        -0.2392742  0.8981817
 Odds Ratio                 0.8175118         NA
tiktok_ban                  9.2942707  2.8305722
 Odds Ratio             10985.6518883         NA
child_sex - Male:Female     0.6758367  0.9786733
 Odds Ratio                 1.9660930         NA

I leave the CIs and the plot to you.

@jay-sf, Thank you , Jay. Should I apply Rubin's Rules for the predicted values as well ?

@CliftonPinto Good question. You could try predict instead of summary, not sure if predict.lrm has a se.fit=TRUE option, though. Then Rubin's rule should apply analogously with the mean predictions, and within and between variances. To be sure, you could ask this on Cross Validated. Keep me posted!

@jay-sf, Thanks, will do.
